# Using JdbcUserDetailsManager vs own UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am learning about Spring Security and I don't understand completly if I should use `JdbcUserDetailsManager` or a custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`. I am using a database for storing users.

I don't get what the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` gives you apart from a lot of methods, which I am not sure that I want to use? What if you have validations etc? Do you wrap it in a own implementation of `UserDetailsService`?

I mean, would you leak this manager class througout your  application. Is it better to create your own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some differences:

1. [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) is the core interface to load user details and is used by [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html).
2. `UserDetailsService` has a sub-interface the defines *CRUD* operations on the abstraction of a user: [`UserDetailsManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/UserDetailsManager.html)
3. [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) is a JDBC implementation of `UserDetailsService`.
4. [`JdbcUserDetailsManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html) is a JDBC implementation of `UserDetailsManager` and an extension of `JdbcDaoImpl`. It also provides the interface [`GroupManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/GroupManager.html)

Based on the differences, it may affect how you decide which to use, expose, wrap or even implement.

Comment: Okey, so I guess JdbcUserDetailsManager have the logic for checking the password etc too? Which a plain implementation of the UserDetailsService does not have?

Comment: I believe it's good to look at [AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java) and [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java). The actual check of the credentials happens in these two classes.

Comment: However, how can JdbcDaoImpl be used as an authentication provider? I can't see where it implements the interface?

Comment: It's not JdbcDaoImpl's responsibility to authenticate. There's a method `DaAuthenticationProvider#setUserDetailsService` and that's how they're glued for authentication process.